# Only add the org files to the agenda if they exist

Tags: org-agenda

I only want certain files to be added to the agenda. I'm using the following code to achieve that:

```
(use-package org-agenda
  :ensure nil
  :custom
  (org-agenda-files
   (list
    (concat org-directory "/bookmarks.org")
    (concat org-directory "/calendar.org")
    (concat org-directory "/contacts.org")
    (concat org-directory "/work.org"))))
```

The problem is that if the files don't exist in the `org-directory` then Emacs will complain and gives an error. I was wondering if there is a way to rewrite the code above in such a way that the files are only added if they are available. Also, if the `org-directory` is not available at all I don't want to receive a warning either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```elisp
(seq-filter #'file-exists-p
            (mapcar #'(lambda (file) (file-name-concat org-directory file))
                    '("bookmarks.org"
                      "calendar.org"
                      "contacts.org"
                      "work.org")))
```

The [`seq-filter`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html#index-seq_002dfilter) function only appends items to the newly returned list, if the predicate returns `t`.  In this case, the predicate is [`file-exists-p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Testing-Accessibility.html#index-file_002dexists_002dp), but you can do whatever specific thing you like, including a lambda, of course.  Instead of passing the files, and concatenating the name manually, this code snippet does so programmatically, using [`mapcar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html#index-mapcar).  Now you can add files ad nauseum.  They are just a list of strings.

Comment: `seq-take-while` will not work: if the first item does not exist, the rest are going to be ignored as well (untested, but the doc you linked to seems pretty clear). I think you want `seq-filter`.

Comment: @NickD Rats, I meant [`seq-filter`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sequence-Functions.html#index-seq_002dfilter).  Editing... thanks!